# dllexport with nested classes

Tags: c++, dllexport

In a DLL I am working on, I have following class I'd like to export:

```
class A {

public:
    class B
    {
        std:string placeholder;
    };

    boost::shared_ptr<B> sp;
};
```

With that code I need to dllexport `A`, `A::B` and `boost::shared_ptr<A::B>`. I'm unable to dllexport `boost::shared_ptr<A::B>` (which I have to do at namespace level) before declaring `A::sp`, because `class A::B` is not known yet. Declaring it like that:

```
class A::B;
```

does not work. Declaring it like that:

```
class B;
```

actually declares another class. How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean `A::B` is not know yet?  `B` is a complete empty class by the time you hit `boost::shared_ptr<B> sp;`

Comment: @NathanOliver It took me a while to figure out too. The problem is that to work correctly, you'd need the namespace-scope declaration `template __declspec(dllexport) boost::shared_ptr<A::B>;` *between* the declaration of `A::B` and that of `A::sp`.

Comment: @Angew Oh, nice.  You should put that in the answer box :-)

Comment: @NathanOliver Except that it's a clarification, not a solution. You cannot tear a class definition in half. I just edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: I've added placeholder var, so `A::B` i s no longer empty.